# How to get the raw value of the url in a link field

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I'm doing this:

```
$link = $node->field_link->first();
if ($link) {
  $url = $link->getUrl()->toString();
  ...
}
```

If the value in the link field is `/node/123` but there is a URL alias defined as:

```
Alias: /about-us    System path: /node/123
```

I get `/about-us` in `$url`. I want to get `/node/123`.

How do I get the raw url value instead of the aliased value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of rendering the URL object with toString() use the method [Url::getInternalPath](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AgetInternalPath/8.8.x):

```
$url = $link->getUrl();
if ($url->isRouted()) {
  $path = $url->getInternalPath();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I happened upon since I first posted is

```
$uri = $node->get('field_link')->uri;
```

The difference between this and the accepted answer is that this approach gives the actual, raw value in the link field (with 'internal:' appended to the front) whatever it is, without URL alias translation. The accepted answer doesn't translate `/node/123` in the field to `/about-us`, but it does translate `/about-us` in the field to `/node/123`.

Once `$uri` has been modified as needed, it can be put back into the node by

```
$node->set('field_link', ['uri' => $uri]);
```